# Failing to authenticate my React frontend with backend using google-auth-login: Failing likely due to polyfills missing in react-scripts 5

Tags: reactjs, django, google-oauth, google-cloud-run, google-auth-library

I deployed both my backend (Django) and frontend (React create-app) services to Google Cloud Run.
As long as my Django service doesn't require authentication, everything works great.

I've tried following this [doc on authenticating service-to-service](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service?cloudshell=true) but without any success. As soon as I import google-auth-login, my react app errors out with a series of dependency missing (browserify, url, crypto, etc). I've read from other questions that this is due to react-scripts 5 missing polyfills.

I've tried to download them and add the fallbacks to my webpack.config.js as directed by the error messages but even when I add them all and resolve this issue I run into a series of warnings/errors , failing to parse different modules like: 'node_modules/https-proxy-agent/src/agent.ts', 'node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js.map', 'node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/iam.js.map' etc.

What am I doing wrong?
Are there alternatives to using google-auth-login to authenticate my frontend service? Should I just deploy those outside of Google Cloud Run?

Comment: Is your frontend client-side?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: So, if your code run on client side (on the browser of the user), do you think you can perform service to service authentication? Indeed, the code doesn't run on the frontend service and can't leverage the service identity to perform a secure call. The call is performed from the client's browser. In that case, the authentication must be generated by the browser. Firebase Auth and API Gateway (or apigee) can help you to solve that challenges.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up setting up the API gateway for the backend, and used Auth0 to get tokens on the client side and pass them to the backend. I now get 401 errors in the API logs `jwt_authn_access_denied{Jwt_is_missing}` even though running the same request with the same token from curl succeeds. Not sure what I'm still doing wrong, would really appreciate any leads.

Comment: If you use API Gateway, the API GATEWAY is the proxy of the connection. Be sure that your API Gateway service account has the correct permission to invoke the service. Share your endpoint definitions if you are not sure

Comment: Thanks! So I made sure the API Gateway service account had Run Invoker permissions and validated axios is indeed passing the header with token to the API and that it includes an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header too. Yet, I'm getting an error `Access to XMLHttpRequest [...] has been blocked by CORS policy [...] : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`. I've also made sure to add `allowCors: true` in my openAPI definition and added the frontend + gateway service urls to my django CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST setting list without much success.